# Problem with file management (open command not recognized)

Tags: python, filesystems, discord.py

I have a problem where I have basically 2 separate python files, where 1 file works perfectly, but other doesn't seem to try to work at all.
I set up logging for messages in general, where it works fine, code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
import emoji

f = open("assets/info/token.txt", "r")
TOKEN = f.readline()
f.close()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f"[{datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}] [{message.guild}] [{message.channel}] {message.author}: {message.content}")
    try:
        log = open(f"assets/info/logging/messages/[{datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}] EGTAB.txt", "a")
        log.writelines(emoji.demojize(f"\n[{datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}] [{message.guild}] [{CHANNEL}] {message.author}: {message.content}"))
        log.close()
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print(f"[{datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}] [{message.guild}] [DEBUG] Unicode (Non-Emoji) Detected but not Resolved.")
        log = open(f"assets/info/logging/messages/[{datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}] EGTAB.txt", "a")
        log.writelines(f" [Unknown Author]: {message.content}")
        log.close()

client.run(TOKEN)
```

This code above works perfectly for me, but this doesn't seem to co-operate:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
import emoji

f = open("assets/info/token.txt", "r") # WORKS!
TOKEN = f.readline()
f.close()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    egtab = client.get_guild(here was guild int, moderated)
    if message.guild == egtab:
        if message.channel.name.lower().find("egtab") != -1:
            print(f"[{datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}] [{message.channel}] {message.author} ({message.author.id}): {message.content}")
            try:
                log = open(f"assets/info/Ticket System/[{datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}] {message.channel}.txt", "a")
                log.writelines(emoji.demojize(f"\n[{datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}] [{message.channel}] {message.author} ({message.author.id}): {message.content}"))
                log.close()
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                print(f"[{datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}] [DEBUG] Unicode (Non-Emoji) Detected but not Resolved.")
                log = open(f"assets/info/logging/messages/[{datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}] {message.channel}.txt", "a")
                log.writelines(f" [Unknown Author]: {message.content}")
                log.close()
        else:
            return
    else:
        return
```

The open command is usually in color, but on errored one it's not, at writelines it's highlighted in yellow on pycharm and the error is: Unresolved attribute reference 'writelines' for class 'Coroutine'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-solved.

It was a mistake using "open" as a command for Discord users. The system thought that I was referring to "open" function rather than the file management.

Removing function:

```
@client.command()
async def open(ctx)
   ... code ...
```

fixed the problem.

Other way to solve this is by putting the "open" function under the code mentioned in the question post.